# How to put iOS app in full screen

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to know how to remove the status bar under ios please.
On android I do not have this problem, but on iOS the status bar is still visible.

Thank you in advance for your answers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
```

Or

//add the following code in config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
 </platform>
```

Comment: I do this but it still doesn't work
`.run(function($ionicPlatform,$document, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.hide();
    }
  });
})`

Comment: you are using two $ionicPlatform in .run function

Comment: I do not know if I'm doing it wrong, but window.Statusbar is not set when I try to display it in console

Comment: install to device and test once. because it may not supporting in browser

Comment: I have succeeded, I used Xcode and it worked :) thanks for your help